Limit of functions that can have 2 values
For a question say $\lim_{x \to 7} \frac{|x-7|}{x-7}$, when we input the value of $x =7$ and solve the question ends up having a $\frac 0 0$ indeterminate form. But here we do not manipulate the question instead we open the mod and take two scenarios $(x-7)$ and $(-x+7)$. So in short can it be concluded that the limits of functions like mod , signum are found by opening the function and not manipulating. It would be extremely helpful if someone could please explain how to solve limits qs correctly and explain the logic asto why we substitute the number to which $x$ is tending to, to find out whether the function is indeterminate or not.

Please - consider learning $\LaTeX$

Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456830

Limits from the left and right may take different values. Then the limit does not exist.
